# JS Position fixed & Android / iOS differences

Tags: javascript, android, ios, android-softkeyboard, mobile-browser

Recently i am working on a mobile webapp with a big textarea that needs to constantly display two little buttons on the bottom corners of the viewport. So i started with the basics:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 10px;
```

This works smoothly and looks beautiful on my target devices (iOS >=5, Android >= 2.3). However, the problem starts when i give my big textarea a focus() and a system keyboard appears.

In iOS browsers, the keyboard is just an overlay on the viewport - so the viewport keeps it's dimensions after keyboard is on and half of it is just hidden under it.

In most android devices the keyboard appearance makes the viewport's height smaller and fitted to the remaining area so my position fixed workes here. However, some android devices work just like iOS and the keyboard appears as an overlay.

I'm trying to think of the best way to cover this, not using user agent string. I want this to be a universal solution. I figured out sth like

```
//check the viewport height
on(focus) -> see if viewport size changed and change position: fixed
```

But to do this i still need to wait couple seconds after focus to let the window get resized or not + i don't really know where to put my buttons if the viewport stays the same, as i might be on any of the iOS systems (the have different sizes fo keyboard) or on android device with bad behaviour.

What do You think?